# ssh is not working smoothly. stuck from time to time...why?

Tags: ssh

This might be hard ...

I have the key ssh user so I normally sync file to server automatically, recently it stopped.

Then I tried rsync manually, it stuck there,

then I tried ssh , sometimes I can log in to the server fast , sometimes no.

And after I log in the server, it stuck after I enter into a few deeper directories...

I am wondering if there is something wrong with local linux or something else...

And there is no error messages displayed

Comment: This sounds more like a disk issue than an ssh issue. Where have you checked for errors - I'd first have a look in /var/log/messages. Are there multiple volumes/disks involved - do you get similar behaviour on other volumes/disks? I'd be condisering running fsck on the volume in question.

Answer (score 0):

- Do you have log entries that might help?
- What is the system load when things start to get slow?
- Did you do a disk and file system check?
- How is the network load on the path to your server?

Answer (score 0):

> then I tried ssh , sometimes I can log
>   in to the server fast , sometimes no

Maybe this is DNS related. check if your SSHd do some reverse lookup and check if your dns resolver is configured properly.